# git diff with parent 1 - 2

Tags: windows, git, tortoisegit

I was looking at the log in Tortoise, and this message is there
Commit:ab77ac9ca5264c531586ad9c5f007395d3e7ae9b

- Merge branch 'master' of repo:R:/AAL/dotNET/OPDash

and also "Diff with parent 1" and "Diff with parent 2" not sure what I should do.

Should I just run the merge option in Tortoise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the log indicates that somebody (e.g. you) already did a merge.
this is what happens, if your local branch diverges from a tracked branch and you "pull" from the diverged upstream.

git will try to automatically merge your branch and the pulled branch, that's where you get the generic log message from.

in general, you should inspect any changesets coming from outside and which you don't trust 100% before merging them.

Comment: so then its ok, but would that message go away at some point?

Comment: messages in logs don't ever go away (unless you rewrite history). however, if the merge is not pushed yet to a public server, you could try to rebase your local branch on the pulled one (eventually fixing any conflicts), so you can avoid the diverge/merge

Comment: I am also a new user of this and gave me a good scare. In most of the cases this is nothing to worry about. Check the files in your directory for the intended content. Chances are they are fine. However, tools that are as confusing at this I call "disaster".

Comment: @AlexeiOst so what would be the proper way to deal with the situation where the remote repository and yours have diverged, and you have told git *explicitely* to "fetch from and integrate with another repository" (quoting the first line in `git help pull`). if you don't want the "integrate" part, then you should just do a `git fetch`

Comment: Hey umlaute, I was not referring to this particular situation, actually. But still I think the situation could be helped by better messages explaining what parent1 and parent2 mean. For example, replacing parent1 with something like "revision blah from of remote repository". Tortoise Git actually made it a bit clearer because it shows them and from there it can be guessed. In general, though, I have seen many posts complaining at considerable learning curve. BTW, I'd say git help is quite hard to read for a novice: many options for many commands with terminology like "hunk" and "cherry pick"..